How to modify requestHeaders on browser extentions javascript
I am developing a "basic" extension (addon) in firefox to modify the request headers I followed the official documentation here (copy/paste but didn't work) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders#details_2  changed it to the example below and still can't make it work.
In my manifest I am asking for all the permits mentioned in the documentation:
//manifest.json
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "storage",
        "tabs"
  ],
  ...
}


//background.js
let currentUserAgent = '';

function updateUserAgent(userAgent) {
  currentUserAgent = userAgent;
  console.log('User agent updated:', currentUserAgent); // User agent updated: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
  console.log("Registering onBeforeSendHeaders event listener..."); //Registering onBeforeSendHeaders event listener...
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    handleRequest,
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
  );
  console.log(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.hasListener(handleRequest)); //true
}

function handleRequest(details) {
  console.log('Handling request:', details); //NO LOG

  // Check if the 'user-agent' header exists
  const userAgentHeader = details.requestHeaders.find(header => header.name.toLowerCase() === 'user-agent');
  if (userAgentHeader) {
    console.log('User-Agent header found:', userAgentHeader.value); //NO LOG
    userAgentHeader.value = currentUserAgent;
    console.log('User-Agent header updated:', userAgentHeader.value); //NO LOG
  } else {
    console.log('User-Agent header not found in the request headers.'); // NO LOG
  }

  return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
}

// Retrieve the saved user agent on startup
chrome.storage.local.get('userAgent', (data) => {
  updateUserAgent(data.userAgent || 'Default User Agent');
});

// Listen for messages to update the user agent
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
  if (message.action === 'updateUserAgent') {
    updateUserAgent(message.userAgent);
  }
});


Any ideas on how to make it work?
Other things I tried:
Changing the object chrome to browser, the result doesn't change.
How do I know is not working?
When I go to the network tab the UA header hasn't change. I also used burpsuite to capture the request and in fact the headers did not change.

You said:
I followed the official documentation here (copy/paste but didn't work)

I know it's been a while since you asked the question, so maybe you already know the answer, but you said:
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ],
  ...
}

You should make that:
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  ...
}

You need permission to intercept the URLs. When you specify the urls property for the filter, that's all it does: filter. If you don't have permission for the URLs, then there's nothing going in the filter, so there's nothing coming out.
You should replace chrome with browser, as you said you did.  Sooner or later chrome will go away.
Depending on what else you're doing, you probably don't need tabs. You definitely don't need it for the snippet in the question.
